# Emscripten 2.0.8 to 2.0.24 caused breaking change

Tags: c++, clang, webassembly, emscripten

With Emscripten 2.0.8 I could build the wasm with following command

```
emcc Test.cc -O3 -std=c++14 -I "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\include" "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_core.a" "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_calib3d.a" "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_features2d.a" "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_flann.a" "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_imgproc.a" "F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_video.a" -s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED -s USE_ZLIB=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -pthread --no-entry --bind -o Test.html
```

But now after upgrading Emscripten to 2.0.24, if I try to build exact same file with exact same static libraries with exact same command I am getting error like following

`wasm-ld: error: F:\OpenCV4.5.2\lib\libopencv_core.a(check.cpp.o): undefined symbol: std::__2::basic_string<char, std::__2::char_traits<char>, std::__2::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__2::basic_string<char, std::__2::char_traits<char>, std::__2::allocator<char> > const&) wasm-ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)`

Can anyone please help me to reshape my command to build with Emscripten 2.0.24?

Comment: Did you also rebuild the dependencies?

Comment: Honestly, no I am using dependency built with version 2.0.4 in Ubuntu. Let me build them once again and give it a try. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks it resolved my problem. Please add this to answer so that I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message mentions a symbol missing from `libopencv_core.a`. The first thing to try would be recompiling everything (including all the dependencies) with the same compiler, in case the new one is not backwards compatible with the old one.